# Planck on the entropy of light

Tags: optics, entropy, thermal-radiation

While reminiscing of his discovery of the quantum of action Planck writes in his "Scientific Autobiography" [1]:

> Thus the nature of entropy as a measure of probability, in the sense indicated by Boltzmann, was established in the domain of radiation, too. This was made especially clear in a proposition, the validity of which my closest pupil, Max von Laue, convinced me in a number of conversations—namely, that the entropy of two coherent pencils of light is smaller than the sum of the entropies of the individual
> pencils of rays, quite consistently with the proposition that the probability of the happening of two mutually interdependent reactions is different from the product of the individual reactions.

What does Planck (or Laue) mean by the entropy of a "coherent pencil of light"? Or by perchance they are talking about thermal radiation that is split into two, say, by "Fresnel's mirror", and then combined to interfere with each other?

[1] Max Planck: Scientific Autobiography and Other Papers, Philosophical Library, [www.philosophicallibrary.com](http://www.philosophicallibrary.com)